# What's the best way to add an element in an existing class element with basic j.s , jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

Say I had some code in HTML like:

```
<div id="some_element" class="element_class">
```

How do I add/create a new div element and add it to the "element_class" with j.s/jQuery?

Comment: google would be a start. 99.99% sure this is a duplicate

Comment: Oh I love snarkiness. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this using only javascript

```
var createDiv = document.createElement('div');
createDiv.textContent='inner div';
document.getElementById('some_element').appendChild(createDiv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

To add elements at the end

```
$('#some_element').append("<div>1</div><div>2</div>");
```

To add element in in the starting

```
$('#some_element').prepend("<div>1</div><div>2</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mybutton").click(function () {
     if($('.newDiv').length !== 1){
       $("#some_element").append("<div class = 'newDiv'>This is a new div</div>");
     }
    });
});
```

```css
 .newDiv{
         height: 80px;
         width: 40px;
         background: yellow;
         border: 1px solid black;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "mybutton">Click me</button>
<div id="some_element" class="element_class">
```